# In python SQLAlchemy model, Why are some attributes initialized twice?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In this piece of code:

```
class Page(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'page'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(Text, unique=True)
  data = Column(Text)

  def __init__(self, name, data):
    self.name = name
    self.data = data
```

Which is a *model* in pyramid framework (the python framework), And will be later used by SQLAlchemy, *name* and *data* are initialized twice:

```
name = Column... # First assignments.
self.name = name # Second time assignments.
```

It's in pyramid's tutorial, And according to the fact that assignment operator can not be overloaded in python, Is "name = Column(...)" necessary?
Or am i totally wrong and name=Column(...) has some special meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer scope is declaring a field for the benefit of the class.  The inner scope is initializing the object's field to a particular value.

```
name = Column(...)
```

is describing one of the members of the `Page` class ("`Page` is composed of a field called '`name`', ...), whereas

```
self.name = name
```

is initializing one particular instance of `Page` to one particular value.  ("this `Page()` has a name of `"framistan"`).

Answer (score 0):

They aren't initialized twice.  The first occurance of each is defining the class attribute (and assigning what I make an educated guess to be a descriptor to it), the second is initializing the attribute of the actual instance to a given value.